# how to get text from hidden input element nested in a div

Tags: jquery, input, selector, hidden

I have the following html code:

```
<a class="tog" href="#">Click Me</a> 
<div class="result">
    <input type="hidden" name="hid" value="val01" />
    This is a container div
</div> <br />
<a class="tog" href="#">Click Me</a> 
<div class="result">
    <input type="hidden" name="hid" value="val02" />
    This is a another container div
</div>
```

How can I get value from hidden input on click of `<a>`? I am trying with this jquery code but it is failing to retrieve value from those hidden input element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".tog").click(function(){
   var $this=$(this);
 if (!$this.next(".result").data('loaded')){ 
   alert($this.next("input[name=hid]").val());
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Try `$this.next().find("input[name=hid]").val()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple

```
$(".tog").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.next(".result").data('loaded')) {
        alert($this.next(".result").children("input:hidden").val());
    }
});
```

Comment: According to me, this is simplest, so I marked it, although all answers are useful. If there were option to accept more than one answers, I would mark others also.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".tog").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.next(".result").data('loaded')) {
        alert($this.next().find("input[name=hid]").val());
    }
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FFTWV/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that, you are using the [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) which is by documentation is used to  *Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.*. here your '$this' points to the anchor, and when you try to execute `$this.next("input[name=hid]").val()` it dont have any immediate sibling named "hid", thats why you are getting am undefined.

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tog").click(function(){
       var $this=$(this);
    alert($this.next("div").find("input[name=hid]").val());   
     });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/QxADt/3/)

Comment: Thankyou very much to all of you for very quick reply. Although the solution is very simple but it was harder for me as I am novice to jquery. My problem is solved now. Thanks again to everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Get the next element which is the div with the result class. From there you find the hidden Input and get it's value.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LctTZ/)

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tog").click(function(){
        var atag = $(this);
        var hiddenInput = atag.next().find('input[type=hidden]');
        alert(hiddenInput.val());         
    });
});
```